# Git branching model | Merging master and release branch

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

We follow a basic release/master/feature branching model where

- Master is the main line
- Every new feature is developed on a new feature branch carved out from master and merged into master, and
- A release branch is carved out of master as and when a release is planned.

After the release branch is carved out, if any issues are found during the QA/UAT testing or after the release, we fix it on the release branch itself. How do we ensure every such fix is present on master as well? Common suggestion would be to merge the release branch into master. This sounds fine but in case where the fix on the release branch is not absolutely correct (say a hack has been introduced due to time constraints) and master has the appropriate fix, we will not want the hack to be merged into master from the release branch. Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: I don’t see the problem. You create a fix branch from release and merge the hack back into release. Done. Master is not affected and will receive the proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a new branch based on release, merge master on it, adapt the fix and then make a pull request to master with that mixed branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this issue in different ways. I'll suggest you a branching model/strategy used in most common open source project I use daily.

Like you, the main line is branch called master. Master contains next release. Master is your release branch. If you are in 42.43 version, ... mater contains release from 42.43.0 to 42.43.*. Where * is the number of path/fixes.

Now, ... Suppose to have a new release to build, with breaking changes or some huge refactoring. Now it is the time to create branch 42.43, and bump to version 42.44 if you have little modifications or 43.0.

Master will be the former or the latter. The development release always stay in mater branch. Old maintainable versions stay in they branch.

### how to put in main development fixes?

Suppose to have versions

- master (you are preparing version 3.0.0)
- 2.4    (the previous version)
- 1.7    (an old version)

If you found a bug in 1.7, just start a branch from there. Probably you'll have tag 1.7.42. In 1.7 branch you are building 1.7.* releases. Just ...

- open branch from 1.7
- take a look latest tag (I use git describe --tags for help)
- fix the minor release
- tag new path 1.7.(+1)

When you have finished, ... just merge branch 1.7 into 2.4. Tag new 2.4.(+1). And do the same until master branch.

```
   -----*----* this is master
       /   /
 -----*----* this is 2.4
     /
----*-- this is 1.7
```

Hope this helps